# How to distinguish the double click and single click of mouse in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

**Q1:** Is there a mouse single click event in `wxpython`.  I didn't find a single click event. So I use `Mouse_Down` and `Mouse_UP` to implement that.
**Q2:** I also have a double click event. But double click event can emmit mouse up and down also.  How can I distinguish them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To distinguish click and double click you can use [wx.Timer](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Timer):

1. Start the timer in OnMouseDown
2. In OnDoubleClick event handler stop the timer
3. If timer wasn't stopped by OnDoubleClick you can handle single click in the timer handler.

[Similar discussion in Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wxpython-users/oQ1BmJOC2UY/kYLnyi-iBUIJ).

Code example (needs polishing and testing of course but gives a basic idea):

```
import wx

TIMER_ID = 100

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(350,200))
        self.timer = None
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)

    def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        print("double click")

    def OnSingleClick(self, event):
        print("single click")
        self.timer.Stop()

    def OnLeftDown(self, event):
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, TIMER_ID)
        self.timer.Start(200) # 0.2 seconds delay
        wx.EVT_TIMER(self, TIMER_ID, self.OnSingleClick)



app = wx.App(redirect=True)
top = Frame("Hello World")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: There is no need to rebind the wx.EVT_TIMER event handler on each left-down.  I would move it to the __init__ method and switch it to use the self.Bind syntax.  I would also reuse the same timer object instead of creating a new one each time.